# Not getting any output in Django for BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, render

I am trying BeautifulSoup4 in Django and I parsed an XML page with it. When I try the parsing the same XML page in a python interpreter in a different way, it works fine. But in Django, I get a page as shown below.

[image]

views.py:

```
def rssfeed(request):
    list1=[]
    xmllink="https://rss.sciencedaily.com/computers_math/computer_programming.xml"
    soup=BeautifulSoup(urlopen(xmllink),'xml')
    for items in soup.find_all('item'):
        list1.append(items.title)
    context={
        "list1":list1
    }
    return render(request,'poll/rssfeed.html',context)
```

rssfeed.html:

```
{% if list1 %}

<ul>
    {% for item in list1 %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would put some print statements in there or a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` line in there to pop into an interactive interpreter and see what is going on. Also, I think the `{% if list1 %}` is unnecessary, because if the list is empty the for loop won't create any template code anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that as I just started learning. But with reference to the second point, I thought I might an else statement later and print something.

Comment: So what do you see in your terminal window when you add `print(items.title)` right before `list1.append(items.title)` or if you put `print(list1)` right before the `return` statement? Running your code I got a list of titles wrapped in `<title>` tags, which I assume is what you are expecting. However, it looks like for you each `{{ item }}` is an empty list `[]` which is very strange...I just noticed that you mention that in your question as well, that it works for you in a Python interpreter, which is where I tested it.

Comment: Also, you could try removing any compiled `.pyc` files from your Django project to see if you are just seeing the effects of older code.

Comment: `print(list1)` prints all the titles in the terminal. But `{{ item }}` still returns an empty list

Comment: Could you show all (or at least more of) rssfeed.html?

Comment: That's the entire code in rssfeed.html . There's nothing more in it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get text from XML, you need to call get_text() function.

Don't use:

```
items.title
```

Use:

```
items.title.get_text()
```

Also, it's recommended to use **lxml** for parsing. Install lxml python and use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(xmllink), 'lxml-xml')
```

Comment: Thanks mate ! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)

> If any part of the variable is callable, the template system will try calling it.

and

> Occasionally you may want to turn off this feature for other reasons, and tell the template system to leave a variable uncalled no matter what. To do so, set a do_not_call_in_templates attribute on the callable with the value True.

And from [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all)

> Calling a tag is like calling find_all()

Eg. `tagX('a')` returns a list of all the `<a>` tags found within this `tagX`.

The `item` in your template refers to instance of `bs4.element.Tag`, which is callable. So Django is calling the `item` variable with zero arguments, which means it will return list of all the elements inside `item`, which is none as it contains only text. Hence the blank lists.

So either parse the context before passing it to the template

```
list1 = [item.title.text for item in soup.find_all('item')]
```

Or if you want to pass the instance for some reason, you can set the `do_not_call_in_templates` attribute to to

```
for item in soup.find_all('item'):
    title = item.title
    title.do_not_call_in_templates = True
    list1.append(title)
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. But even after changing that, I get a page with only bullets as shown in the question above after my edit.

Comment: Updated accordingly, but will try to find a better solution.. Solutions from Django documentation are not working properly (or maybe I'm interpreting them wrongly).